# How can I code my sql query to Laravel query

Tags: laravel-5.8

How can I convert following sql query to Laravel query?

```
SELECT roster_date, COUNT(DISTINCT truck_id) AS available_units
FROM truck_rosters
WHERE(truck_rosters.status = 'Active')
```

### GROUP BY roster_date

and merge with this query:

SELECT roster_date, COUNT(DISTINCT truck_id) AS total_units
FROM truck_rosters
GROUP BY roster_date

---

Expected result:

### roster_date    |  total_units   |  available_units

2019-08-30     |     11         |        3
2019-08-31     |     10         |        4

Comment: Please provide more information, e.g. of what you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation for the two counts:

```
$rosters = DB::table('truck_rosters')
    ->select(DB::raw("COUNT(DISTINCT truck_id) AS total_units,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Active' THEN 1 END) AS active_units, roster_date"))
    ->groupBy('roster_date')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks man. But I have an addition query to merge to you're answer

SELECT roster_date, COUNT(DISTINCT truck_id) AS total_units
FROM truck_rosters
GROUP BY roster_date

Comment: The expected output is:

Comment: Please don't leave such comments here.  If your question needs to change, then change your question above.

Comment: Roster_date  |  Total_units |  Available_units
------------------------------------------------------------
2019-08-30   |       11        |       3
2019-08-31   |       10        |       2
2019-09-01   |       10        |       4

Comment: Hi Tim, how can I distinct the column active_units? Thanks.